# Mostrar mensaje según condición Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Estoy realizando un reporte en Oracle SQL y en este reporte requiero mostrar un mensaje en un campo correspondiente según estas condiciones

```
BEC_ACCEPTED = Y AND FOR_ACCEPTED IS NULL
```

Pendiente formador

```
BEC_ACCEPTED IS NULL AND BEC_SCHEDULE IS NULL
```

Pendiente beca

La consulta la estoy realizando de la siguiente manera

```
SELECT CODE, ANIO, BEC_ACCEPTED, FOR_ACCEPTED, STATUS FROM RASBE;
```

**Actualizacion:**

El campo donde se mostrara el mensaje se llamara `STATUS`

Comment: probaste con un case?

Comment: @gbianchi Podrías agregar un ejemplo como respuesta para darle validez

Comment: Estoy preguntando si probaste con un case y tuviste algun problema... en realidad en que campo queres guardar la salida? que vas a hacer con los otros campos?

Comment: @gbianchi El mensaje se crearía en un nuevo campo llámese como quiera y lo que voy a hacer con los otros campos incluyendo este los mostraría en el reporte.

Comment: @gbianchi Revisa mi ultima actualización, ahí coloque el campo en el cual mostrare el mensaje

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Según parece lo que buscas puedes lograrlo usando un `CASE`, algo así:

```
SELECT 
CODE, 
ANIO, 
BEC_ACCEPTED, 
FOR_ACCEPTED, 
CASE
    WHEN BEC_ACCEPTED = 'Y' AND FOR_ACCEPTED IS NULL THEN 'PENDIENTE FORMADOR'
    WHEN BEC_ACCEPTED IS NULL AND BEC_SCHEDULE IS NULL THEN 'PENDIENTE BECA'
    ELSE 'OTRA COSA'
END STATUS 
FROM RASBE;
```

Ten en cuenta que si no pones un resultado al `ELSE` los que no cumplan con ninguna de las 2 condiciones aparecerán nulos.